# How do i add a customized underline in css.I want to add a customized underline in anchor tag on hover by CSS

Tags: css

```
<div>
   <a href="#">My Link </a>
</div>
```

I want to add a customized underline in anchor tag on hover by CSS.

Comment: Customised in what way? Color, appearance, thickness, distance from the baseline ...?

Comment: Color, appearance, thickness, distance from the baseline...

Comment: There is a now deleted answer to this question by @thepio which explained you can use border-bottom. For instance, `:hover {border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;}` for a 5px thick underline.

Comment: Thank you so much @MrLister